# Why did my column values change to NaN after I rearranged the order of the column

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

After I used .reindex() to change my column order, the values within column 'Key Passes Per Game' became NaN.

```
messi_dataset = messi_dataset.reindex(columns = ['Season','Team','Competition','Appearances','Minutes','Goals','Assists','Goals+Assists','Goals per 90','Assists per 90','Key Passes Per Game','Shots Per Game','Successful Dribbles','Average Match Rating'])


messi_dataset
```

Comment: NaN is a floating-point number used to represent indeterminate values such as 0/0.  Floating point addition is not necessarily associative.  So check in that area; hope this helps.

Comment: What happens if you do `messi_dataset[the_column_list]`? I would bet for an error if one of the column is missing. That would explain the NaNs

Comment: No the column exists since it had values before i changed the order. Even after I do messi_dataset['Key Passes Per Game'] the table shows up but each value is NaN.

Answer (score 0):

To change the column ordering try:

```
messi_dataset = messi_dataset[['Season','Team','Competition','Appearances','Minutes','Goals','Assists','Goals+Assists','Goals per 90','Assists per 90','Key Passes Per Game','Shots Per Game','Successful Dribbles','Average Match Rating']]
```

Answer (score 0):

Something similar happened to me when I was trying to use my_data = my_data.reindex(columns=column_names).
The column names changed, but the values inside all turned into NaNs.
After many tries I realised I forgot to name one of the columns, so I was giving it less column names than needed. Once I added the missing column name, everything worked.
I suggest chacking again the column names for any missing ones.

Also, using the following syntax is prettier in my opinion than using reindex:
my_data.columns = column_names

Comment: Nice try basically suggesting one column was missing from the original index. However this question cannot be answered as it is, since it is missing the input data. Rather try to focus on questions with full [mre].